# input field showing an URL with quotes

Tags: php, mysql, quotes, mariadb, double-quotes

I have to store some Wikipedia URLs into a MariaDB database.

It happens that some URLs contain quotes, like this one:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Heroes%22

so I use `urlencode()` to store them as `"en.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%22Heroes%22"`.

If I urldecode() the URL, to show it inside an `<input type="text">` field without all the % (they scare unskilled users), the quotes break the `input` value.

I found this workaround to show the result in a more comfortable way:

```
$url = 'en.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%22Heroes%22'; // it comes in this way from the DB
$tmp = str_replace('%22','&quot;', $url);
$url_input = urldecode($tmp);
echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"$url_input\" />";
```

The value of `$url_input` works smoothly as a `<a href` anchor, and the query coming from the form is then filtered with `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` and `urlencode()` to store it in the DB.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use single quotes in HTML -> `value='$url_input'` but then you'd probably want to make sure the url doesn't contain single quotes as well ?

Comment: Like Martha's Vineyard?

Comment: Yes, like that. This is why one should avoid quotes in URL's, Wikipedia just didn't get the message, and replacing the single quotes with doublequotes isn't an option either as the URL wouldn't work. To use in values for inputs the quotes could be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use htmlspecialchars() instead of str_replace()

```
$url = 'en.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%22Heroes%22'; // it comes in this way from the DB
//$tmp = str_replace('%22','&quot;', $url);
$url_input = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($url));
echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"$url_input\" />";
```

I think it will work better than this

Comment: This seems useful to avoid even the Martha's Vineyard single quote, and some other oddities.